# How can I use [Motion] to make an entity follow a path based on the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I get the way the question is formatted, it may sound as if this question has been asked before, and if it has, I'd love to see where I can find it. What I'm struggling with is being able to summon an armor stand that travels a particular path relative to where the player is facing, with the catch being that it isn't adjusted by the players y-axis rotation. I provided a very amateur diagram below just to try and better demonstrate what I mean. I also provided a video for where I got this idea from and where I used the code provided to work on something myself. (

)

I am still learning how to operate with these commands seeing as relative motion was something I was never really great with. If you have any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it as I'm hoping to get a better understanding of how to create more with commands and functions. Thank you[image: Specified diagram that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve]